# Mysql max_connection_per_hour

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am using Hostinger as host provider to host my Laravel project.

All looks good, but suddenly the site went down and when I look at the laravel.logs, I see this error

```
[2019-06-29 00:05:34] production.ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1226] User 'u574239410_orvx' has exceeded the 'max_connections_per_hour' resource (current value: 500) {"exception":"[object] (PDOException(code: 1226): SQLSTATE[HY000] [1226] User 'u574239410_orvx' has exceeded the 'max_connections_per_hour' resource (current value: 500) at /home/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:68)
```

I am not root user for mysql

I've tried this:

```
set global max_connections = 200;
```

But no improvement.  Please help me

Comment: so what to do now

Comment: #1193 - Unknown system variable 'max_connections_per_hour'

Comment: Sorry, looks like I was wrong about that. The naming is very odd and misleading. I'll delete my bad comments. There are lots of Google hits for `max_connections_per_hour`, though, which show that it can be a per-user setting. Maybe check some of those, and if you still don't get it to work, post here with what you tried and what results it had.

Comment: If you're on a hosted system you probably don't have rights to set global parameters on the MySQL service, and you probably don't have rights to set the individual quotas on each user. You probably need to talk to your hosting company about a bigger package, or look to an Amazon instance to run your own server.

Comment: Have you tried to contact your hosting company and ask them to raise the limit? 500 seems to be too low. Also, look here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/156391/root-max-connections-per-hour-exceed

Comment: I know nothing about Hostinger but all the symptoms suggest it's an intentional resource limit imposed by the company in order to sustain a very cheap (or even free) shared hosting service. If so, you get what you pay for ;-) You may want to try luck with persistent connections, but you then might hit another limit.

Answer (score 0):

Maximum number of connections in MySQL can be limited globally, per user and per hour.

max_connections is global limit, max_user_connections for user.

Default max_connections is set to 100, if not changed from my.ini.